# A positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

Let
\begin{equation}%\nonumber
A:=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
be a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix with $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ $(i,j=1,\dotsc,3)$. An observation $(x)(x)=(1)(x^2)$ leads to the fact that the following two statements are equivalent:

(1) $f(x):=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  x & x^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
x\\
x^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

(2) For any $m\in\mathbb{R}$, $g(x,Y):=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  x & Y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}-\frac{m}{2}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}+m & a_{23}\\
a_{31}-\frac{m}{2} &a_{32}  & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
x\\
Y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ge0$ for $x,Y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Does this implies that the following two problems are equivalent?

(1) Find all $a_{ij}$ $(i,j=1,2,3)$ such that
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  x & x^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
x\\
x^2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

(2) Find all $a_{ij}$ $(i,j=1,2,3)$ such that for any $m\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  x & Y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}-\frac{m}{2}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}+m & a_{23}\\
a_{31}-\frac{m}{2} &a_{32}  & a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
x\\
Y\\
\end{bmatrix}
\ge0
$$
for $x,Y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Any reference, suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think those are equivalent

Comment: Do you have some reason?

Comment: because you can choose $m$ huge, both positive and negative. Those almost surely have NOT the same sign